# How to create two way binding in Angular dynamic data table?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I used dynamic data table as below:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" mat-table matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" dir="rtl"
  [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" matColumnDef="{{column.columnDef}}">
    <div>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column.label}}</th>
    </div>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let index = index" class="cells">
      <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [placeholder]="column.label" [value]="column.cell(row, column)">
    </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr (click)="showContent(row)" class="rows" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

and this is my typescript code for build columns and data source:

```js
let mhd = {
    columnDef: eachColumns['columnName'],
    label: eachColumns['displayName'],
    cell: (row, c) => {
        return row[c.columnDef];
    }
};
this.columns.push(mhd)

this.displayedColumns = this.columns.map(c => c.columnDef);
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.result);
```

I change data of input 
then console.log(this.result)
but in console i see Previous object.

if i change to `[(value)]="column.cell(row, column)"`
I get this error below in console:

> core.js:14597 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
>   Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 25 in [column.cell(row, column)=$event] in ng:///ReportModule/MainGridReportComponent.html@14:51 ("= index" class="cells">
>         
>         ][(value)]="column.cell(row, column)">
>       
>       
>   "): ng:///ReportModule/MainGridReportComponent.html@14:51

Comment: can you share a working stackblitz for this... easier to help that way

Comment: using [(ngModel)] -the values are in this.dataSource.data- , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59087657/angular-mat-table-editing-individual-column-cells/59088686#59088686, using a FormArray https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59223972/create-dynamic-mat-table-like-math-matrix-with-angular-material/59234386#59234386

Comment: you can not bind function, can you try this: `[value]="row[column.columnDef]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its be right way for two way binding:

```
 [(ngModel)]="row[column.columnDef]"
```